# Mutating variable based upon conditional evaluation of multiple columns in dplyr chain

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Consider the following dataset:

```
  patientID age     age2      age3 equal
1         1  25     25        25   TRUE
2         2  34     34        32   FALSE
3         3  28     28        20   FALSE
4         4  52     18        19   FALSE
```

I want to mutate an `equal` column that is TRUE if `age`, `age2`, and `age3` are equal to each other.  I thought this would be straightforward like so:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(equal = ifelse(age == age_2 == age_3, 1, 0))
```

But I guess R cannot interpret three `==` signs back to back, as it gives an "unexpected symbol, ==" error.  I corrected this like so:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(equal = ifelse(isTRUE(all.equal(age, age_2, age_3)), 1, 0))
```

which returns values of `"FALSE"` for every column.  What is the correct way to do this while avoiding multiple pairwise if statements? (e.g. `(age == age_2) & (age_2 == age_3)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier option is to compare the first column among the 'age' columns with the rest and create a logical condition with `rowSums`.

```
nm1 <- grep("age", names(data))
data$equal <- !rowSums(data[nm1][,1] != data[nm1]) 
data$equal
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

We can also use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
   mutate(equal = pmap(select(., starts_with('age')),
          ~ n_distinct(c(...)) == 1))
#  patientID age age2 age3 equal
#1         1  25   25   25  TRUE
#2         2  34   34   32 FALSE
#3         3  28   28   20 FALSE
#4         4  52   18   19 FALSE
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(patientID = 1:4, age = c(25L, 34L, 28L, 52L), 
    age2 = c(25L, 34L, 28L, 18L), age3 = c(25L, 32L, 20L, 19L
    )), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks akrun!  I had thought of this, but is there really no way to do it within a dplyr chain?  I'm surprised all.equal doesn't work within a grouping variable.

Comment: @Parseltongue  You can use `data %>% mutate(equal = pmap(select(., starts_with('age')), ~ n_distinct(c(...)) == 1))`

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it in `dplyr` would be (using [akrun's data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57010219/6461462)):

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(equal = +(n_distinct(c(age,age2,age3))==1))

#   patientID age age2 age3 equal
# 1         1  25   25   25     1
# 2         2  34   34   32     0
# 3         3  28   28   20     0
# 4         4  52   18   19     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general `tidyverse` solution using `pmap`. We can adjust the `select` function to grab whatever column we want. `pmap` takes each row from the selected columns and checks whether all elements of each row is equal to the first element of the row:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(equal = select(., matches("age")) %>% pmap(~ all(c(...) == ..1)))
```

also with `apply` in Base R:

```
data$equal <- apply(data[grep("age", names(data))], 1, function(x) all(x == x[1]))
```

**Output:**

```
  patientID age age2 age3 equal
1         1  25   25   25  TRUE
2         2  34   34   32 FALSE
3         3  28   28   20 FALSE
4         4  52   18   19 FALSE
```